# Why ClearCase hangs when working with multiple machines?

Tags: clearcase

I am having a ClearCase dynamic view on Win-7 Machine, I added the  ClearCase View Shortcut (Created in Win-7 Machine) to an XP machine.

When I try to compile my project from view mounted in WinXP machine, it hangs, and it requires hard reboot. I tried many times, but I got the same results.
Is there anything to do with Anti-virus settings?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic views can be an issue when scanned by anti-virus: it is best to add m:\ (the mounting point for dynamic views) to the exclusion list of said anti-virus.

I wouldn't recommend accessing a Win7 dynamic view from WinXp, but rather define a dynamic view directly on the Xp.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. check the clearcase version is same on both windows 7 and windows XP.
2. check if you can use that dynamic view, which created in windows 7, to mount vobs, set config spec, and view the files properly. 
3. Check if all clearcase services are started properly.
4. apply the latest windows patch and clearcase patch on both windows 7 and windows xp.
```

If above checks are fine, I don't think the problem is related with anti-virus. I run clearcase client with anti-virus without issue, and I can mount the dynamic view on windows xp which created in windows 7.